# discord.py how do you ignore an error and move on

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a dm announcement command but once it gets an error like dming itself (invoke error) or when someone's dm's are closed (forbidden) the command stops entirely, I have tried using pass aswell and the same thing happens

the code I am using

```py
@bot.command()
async def dann(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        await member.send("test")

    print("Action completed: Message all")

@dann.error
async def man(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
       print('fail')
   elif isinstance(error, commands.Forbidden):
         print('dms closed')
```

or

```py
@bot.command()
async def dann(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    try:
       for member in ctx.guild.members:
           await member.send("test")
    except:
        pass
    print("Action completed: Message all")
```

is there a way for the bot to move on if it finds an error?

Comment: See python docs on [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: Have you searched for it? What did you find?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is "[Python Try Expect"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

it looks something like this:

```py
   try: ## The try block will generate an exception, because x is not defined
      print(x)
   except:
      print("An exception occurred")
```

You can find more info about in the following sources:

- [W3Schools Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)
- [Wiki Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)
- [Programiz Tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)